# table adds the updates sql server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-update

I have the table `tab`, and I want to create a table `History` to insert the updates I made in `tab` table . To do this I've created the trigger `tr_update`, but it doens't work correctly.

```
Create table Tab 
(
id_tab char(5),
data_tab int
)

Create table History 
(id_modify       char(3),
old_data             int,
new_data             int,
)


Create trigger tr_update
on tab
after update
as
declare @id char(3)
declare @old int
declare @new int

select @id=id_tab, @new=data_tab from inserted
select @old=data_tab from deleted

insert into History (id_modify,old_data,new_data)
values (@id,@old,@new)
```

Comment: As written, [your trigger is doomed for failure](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers.aspx). Also, you might want to clarify what "it doens't work correctly" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triggers works with sets of data, meaning that the sets`inserted`and`deleted`can contain more than one row and that simple assignments won't work. Instead you can use`inserted`and `deleted`as source tables (and join them if you want both new and old data, as in this case).

```
Create trigger tr_update
on tab
after update
as

insert into History (id_modify,old_data,new_data)
select i.id_tab, d.data_tab, i.data_tab 
from inserted i
inner join deleted d on i.id_tab = d.id_tab
```

On a side note, it seems the`id_data`filed in the history table only is 3 chars wide, while the original table has it as 5 chars wide. This probably won't work; the field in the history table needs to be the same size (or wider) or else the server won't allow the insert as data might be truncated.